# How to translate "Setsunai"(切ない)

Tags: word-choice, idioms, translation, synonyms, japanese

I'd like to know the equivalent word in English for "Setsunai"(切ない) in Japanese. 
It's the mixture of feelings such as sad, heartache, love and nostalgic.
It's near bitter sweet, I think, but I'd like to know more suitable ones if any.

You feel "setsunai" when you think of your ex-boyfriend.
You also could be "setsunai" when listening to a love song. 
Recently, you could use this word more casually; 
A: "I went to the post office, but it has already closed today."
B: "That's "setsunai" !

Comment: It could have a number of meanings: (1) It's a pity, (2) That's too bad, (3) That must be unbearably painful, (4) I feel sorry for you.

Comment: I think it's not unbearably painful...pains could be in it, but it's more like sentimental and nostalgic. Not necessarily sad...It's always too difficult to explain this word in English...

Comment: I didn't use the word "sad". The reason it is difficult to explain it to foreigners is they don't have any concept or idea about the Chinese character 切 and the expression is used in too many situations where it doesn't have the same connotation. That's probably why.

Comment: @Eri You mention *nostalgia* and *sentimental*; in that vein, does *wistful* fit? Musing about things which might-have-been? Yearning for a future which will never come, a home you'll never find? It's like *melancholy* but much subtler and the focus isn't on sadness, more like regret. That said I can't think of *any* word which would fit your more modern, casual sense. I don't even know what emotion the second person was experiencing about the first person's inability to go to the post office. Can you help us capture the right word by ensnaring it in more quotations, classical and casual?

Comment: You mentioned *heartache*, but your overall description seems to fit that word pretty well. In what way does it not really fit the meaning of the Japanese word?

Comment: @Dan Bron The last example I took might be inaccurate way of using by young people these days. I wanted to describe by the example that this word is often used in different contexts and I wanted to know if English also has any words which are used in similar way. But it may be an inappropriate approach here...sorry for confusing. Young people recently this word just to mean "that's too bad" or "that's unlucky ", but it's not the original meaning of this word. In classical way, "Setsunai" is used for describing a feeling, a love song and a memory.

Comment: @Drew This word contains not only bad feelings but also happy and loving feelings. It's really difficult to describe...Maybe it's impossible to find a word that perfectly fits in English...

Comment: @Eri In that sense (your comment to Drew), bittersweet might be the closest, but I don't think it works. You may be right. There is no counterpart in English and you have to use different adjectives or phrases on case by case basis.

Comment: As for the post-office example (but only the post-office example) :  "That's a bummer!"  [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bummer)  Does the recent "post-office" use degrade the earlier, more soulful meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like melancholy, or wistful?  It doesn't quite fit the last example of the post office, unless the second person is being very dramatic... but either fits the description from the beginning of your definition fairly well.

Alternatively, you might look at the word, "unhappy".  It is a little simpler than some of your connotations imply, since it can also apply to other troubles and situations than those you mention.  It can be profoundly used though, as someone who is sad or heartbroken is quite unhappy, or someone who has an unhappy situation or unhappy life might imply heartbreak or nostalgia for lost love or better times.  However, its simplicity means it can also be used more informally, so one person might say "that's unhappy" to even fairly mundane events like a store or post office being closed for the day.

Answer (score 0):

I actually named 1 of my old songs "Setsunai". My friend Momo described it as "love sick," which perfectly described the emotion I felt when I composed it.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please [explain your answer](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), preferably with some supporting statements and [references](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). While opinions are valued, they are not of much help as answers.